# WCF regarding class property types

Tags: c#, wcf, service, datacontract, datamember

Ok so I am building my WCF service. I am having an issue with my proxy not generating code for classes that have types such as ListViewItem, or even the class objects that I already have defined.

Two examples below are classes that I am trying to pass.

**Example #1**

```
[DataContract]
public class InvoiceCharges {
    #region Property...
    private int _invoiceChargeID;
    private ListViewItem _listViewItem;

    [DataMember]
    public int InvoiceChargeID {
        get { return _invoiceChargeID; }
        set { _invoiceChargeID = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public ListViewItem ListViewItem {
        get { return _listViewItem; }
        set { _listViewItem = value; }
    }
    #endregion
```

**Example #2**

```
[DataContract]
public class Users {
    #region Properties...
    private int _userID;
    private Divisions _Division = new Divisions();

    [DataMember]
    public int UserID {
        get { return _userID; }
        set { _userID = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Divisions Division {
        get { return _Division; }
        set { _Division = value; }
    }
```

In the 2nd example I am confused why it has a hard time just passing my Division class that it already sees. Surely WCF can pass your own custom objects?? Any help is greatly appreciated, I know on other platforms in order to Serialize your own custom object you have to do something special to your class. I wasn't sure if WCF handled this automatically or not.

**EDIT**

Any other help on this is still appreciated.

I have also tried adding the following to the InvoiceCharges class but was still unable to see the proxy generate correctly.

```
[KnownType(typeof(ListViewItem))]
```

Also, this is the behavior of the proxy. I am using Add Service Reference to do this.

[image]

See how it is generating several "InvoiceCharges" its all because of that ListViewItem. I can remove the DataMember attribute off of it and its fine.

Comment: Does the Divisions class have the DataContract attribute on it as well?

Comment: Yes, what is strange is that when I remove the [DataMember] attribute from the custom objects (such as the ListViewItem property and the Division property) that it is having trouble with. The class generates a proxy successfully on the client end.

Comment: Well I'm guessing that ListViewItem isn't marked with the DataContract attribute, so that could be the issue there. Not sure on Divisions class since you didn't post the code.

Comment: Are you sure about putting, DataContract on a property of a class? Attribute 'DataContract' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, struct, enum' declarations.

Comment: For what it's worth, you shouldn't be sending ListViewItem instances over WCF (assuming these are the LVI's built into the framework). They are a UI construct. Just send the data and construct new LVI instances on the other side.

Comment: Chris, my main issue with wanting to keep the ListViewItem reference in there isn't for actually passing that ListViewItem through WCF. We are adding service features to the in-house app. Give me some advice here, I am using the .dll I already made for the application and decorating it with the correct [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes. Is this bad practice, lol probably a stupid?

Comment: @meanbunny Not sure what you mean by "have the class code it needs". If adding services at this layer of your application requires sending UI classes like LVI over the wire, then you should either rethink the layer at which your services are operating or you need to refactor the behavior of the client so that your services send and receive pure POCOs (plain old code objects, e.g. classes with just fields and properties).

Comment: @ChrisShain Ok I see, sorry that was confusing. What I meant, was that I didnt want to add that same dll to the client. I agree I think I need to change which members I am going to send over the wire altogether. I am still very new to WCF, I just figured it would serialize whatever I wanted lol.

Comment: @ChrisShain Ok thank you very much this has helped me out. The ListViewItem was definitely making it angry. I had another ListViewItem in a different custom object "Divisions" that was selected as a [DataMember]. After removing that the client proxy was generated just fine.

Comment: The client's going to need the same DLL regardless. When WCF serializes a class, it just serializes that class's *state*, not the class's *code*. The client needs to have the same assembly (and in fact any dependencies of that assembly) in order to be able to deserialize the class.

Comment: @ChrisShain oh wow ok, I thought that the proxy just handled all of that for me. I guess what I didn't want to happen was that I added the same dll, and add a Service Reference. I guess in my mind I was thinking I would generate ambiguous names.

Answer (score 0):

A ListViewItem is a UI concept and serves no purpose in your business or service code. Rethink the "data" (models) and not what the user sees and retool the class.

Your problem deals with the inability to serialize. Unless you want to rewrite UI bits to make them more serialization friendly, rethinking the model is your best bet.